# How do multi radius skis work in practice

Tags: skiing

Some skis nowadays have a different sidecut radius at the front, center and back of the ski. With the different radius they claim to be suitable for both long and short turns. (So far the theory)
[image: Multi Radius illustration for single ski]
But how does a skier control which radius is actually used? Is this dependent on the edge angle or the load on the center (which would relate it to speed)?
[image: Multi radius illustration]

[Sources](https://www.voelkl.com/en/3-radius-sidecut/)

Comment: Yeah, it's something that requires relatively stiff skis. Basically if you put more pressure during a turn (more aggressively push down on your skis), then the ski bends into the tighter radius in the middle. With flappy planks, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled over an explanation of this in a [ski review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KY1q4QbztsQ&feature=youtu.be&t=175). According to this, the radius in use depends on where you put your pressure. If there is more pressure to the front it will use the longer tip radius. If the pressure is applied more central, the shorter center radius is used.